# Usage of named pipe as data source for netcat

Tags: bash, pipe, netcat, fifo

I want to use netcat as a TCP-server that reads data from a named pipe. For that I did the following:

Step 1. Created a pipe and the server that uses it as a source

```
mkfifo /tmp/all.pipe
nc -k -l 8080 < /tmp/all.pipe
```

Step 2. Created a client that reads the data continuously:

```
while true; do
    sleep 1;
    echo "Check connection";
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf "$line";
    done < /dev/tcp/localhost/8080;
done
```

Step 3. Write some data to the pipe:

```
echo "hello" > /tmp/all.pipe
```

After execution of these 3 steps the output on the client side was:

```
...
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/localhost/8080: Connection refused
Check connection
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/localhost/8080: Connection refused
Check connection
hello
```

However when I executed the step 3 after this again, the output didn't change. Looks like it happened because the connection was still active, but the new data wasn't passed from the pipe to the nc and then to the client. Why? What can be done to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon:

> ```
> nc -k -l 8080 < /tmp/all.pipe
> ```

The shell tries to open `/tmp/all.pipe` and that hangs as there's no process that has opened the named pipe for writing yet.

Since `nc` has not been started yet, that explains why `bash` gets a *connection refused* when trying to connect there.

When you do

> ```
> echo "hello" > /tmp/all.pipe
> ```

Then that's when the first command is unlocked. The pipe is now instantiated.

Then `echo` writes `hello\n` there and terminates,  at which point the writing end of the pipe is closed, and `nc` will see end-of-file on its stdin. If you had used `cat` instead of `nc`, `cat` would have terminated.

But for `nc`, its stdout still goes to the terminal at that point and the TCP connection is still live so even if there's one end that has reached end-of-input, it carries on. If `bash` sent something on that socket, that would be displayed on `nc`'s stdout for instance.

When you do a second `echo something > /tmp/all.pipe`, as `nc` has not closed its fd on the pipe (at least that's the case of the `nc` from the `netcat-openbsd` package on Ubuntu, YMMV), that does go through that same pipe that goes live again, but `nc` has already given up reading from that since it had reached eof earlier.

Easiest here is probably to open the pipe for `nc`'s input in read+write mode so it's instantiated immediately and always live as long as `nc` lives.

For that, just replace `<` with `<>` on the `nc` command line:

```
nc -k -l 8080 <> /tmp/all.pipe
```

Also note that the first  argument to `printf` is the format, you shouldn't have any variable there. If you want to print the input line without the line delimiter, you use:

```
printf %s "$line"
```